# Rails Server stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

No clue why, here is the console output:

```
undefined method `model' for main:Object
/Users/Jerome/Desktop/UrbanImpact/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Jerome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/Jerome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/Jerome/Desktop/UrbanImpact/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Jerome/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/Users/Jerome/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/Jerome/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/Jerome/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/Jerome/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Jerome/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/Jerome/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/Users/Jerome/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Jerome/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/Jerome/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Jerome/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/Jerome/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

This comes up in console after I type in "rails server"

Any help is welcome!

Comment: There's not enough info here. Please include the entire stack trace if one is available. What are you doing when this error comes up?

Comment: Full trace included, and this happens after I type rails server into terminal.

Comment: Is it only when you do a `rails server`? Are you able to open rails console successfully?

Comment: Nah, I can't open rails console either...

Comment: Sadly this actually isn't a full stacktrace (though it might be everything that is displayed for you right now).

Does this error also occur when you run a rake task? (eg rake db:migrate)? If so - you can pass a parameter to rake to get the full stacktrace: `rake db:migrate --trace`

Comment: What is in application.rb line 3?

Comment: @Jerome just paste your `application.rb`

Comment: Yep, you guys were on the right track, there was something stupid there. I deleted it, and it worked like a charm. What perplexes me however, is that it had been working for days, and then all the sudden it realized "hey that's there, and I don't like it..." Anyways thanks for the help. If one of you posts the solution, I'll give it to you.